# linux can't access screens on crontab

Tags: linux, cron, gnu-screen

I have created a bash file that executes a python script on an existing screen called 'cronscreen'. The bash file contains the following line:

```
screen -S cronscreen -X stuff "python test.py$(printf \\r)"
```

When I run the file from the command line, it works fine, and I see the output is printed when I attach my 'cronscreen'. However, I would like it to run in cron, so I have set up crontab as follows:

```
* * * * * myuser /home/myuser/myscript.sh > /home/ec2-user/agg.log
```

The cron is executed because I can see that the file agg.log is regenerated every minute, but when I attach 'cronscreen', I see no output printed there (and agg.log is empty). Why is that? Thanks.

Update:

I also tried changing the script to this(re-attaching the screen), but no change:

```
screen -r cronscreen
screen -S cronscreen -X stuff "python test.py$(printf \\r)"
```

Answer (score 1):

screen needs an tty active to create a session which is not what is available under cron.

You need to split this into two parts , the first is to run screen and make it detach - screen -dmS cronscreen  and then in your cronjob attach to the screen session with -r cronscreen

Comment: you have to do the screen detach from an active session so that it has a tty and you have to use -dmS <name> to do it